# What is out of the normal flow?

Tags: css, overflow, css-position, css-float

What PRECISELY does the **bold text** in the specification refer to?

> Floats, absolutely positioned elements, block containers (such as
> inline-blocks, table-cells, and table-captions) that are not block
> boxes, and block boxes with 'overflow' other than 'visible' (**except
> when that value has been propagated to the viewport**) establish new
> block formatting contexts for their contents.

Answer (score 0):

The overflow value set on the HTML element if it's not "visible", or the BODY element otherwise, is applied to the viewport instead of the HTML/BODY element. The element from which the overflow value is taken is given an overflow value of "visible" instead.

If it's the BODY element's overflow value that has been transferred to the viewport, the element does not establish a block formatting context because of its specified overflow value (though it may do so for other reasons).

If it's the HTML element's overflow value that has been transferred to the viewport, it establishes an independent formatting context (which, in CSS2, is always a block formatting context) anyway, regardless of its overflow value.

Comment: Hi @Alohci I have a question, the viewport is the area visible to the user on a web page. So, is the HTML or BODY element the same as say viewport?

Comment: @GeorgeMeijer - No, [the viewport](https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/#viewport) is a different concept from any element. HTML Elements generate CSS boxes, which are painted on a canvas. The viewport is a window through which one can see a portion of that canvas. The scrollbars on the viewport move that viewport over the canvas changing what part of the canvas is visible.

Comment: Great, thanks, @Alohci, I take the opportunity for another question, Flexbox and Grid Layout come out of the normal flow?

Comment: @GeorgeMeijer - Ordinarily, they're both in normal flow. Floated elements, and Absolute and Fixed positioned elements are out of normal flow.

Comment: thanks @Alohci, so, when an element is put float: left | right; it also "floats" (behind the scenes) above all the site content like absolutely positioned elements?

Comment: @GeorgeMeijer - Not really. "float" in this context just means "separate from" [the normal flow]. Floating does affect the paint order, which will bring it above some elements, but not above absolute positioned elements that have a non-negative z-index in the same stacking context.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Alohci we can conclude then that ONLY the absolutely positioned elements are THE ONLY ones that are ABSOLUTELY ABOVE everything that a website has.